# How to turn a one dimensional array into a two dimensional one where the parents can go more than two levels deep?

Tags: javascript

I have a one dimensional array of objects and each object has an id and an id of its parent. In the initial array I have each element can have at most one child. So if the array looks like this:

```
{id: 3, parent: 5},
{id: 5, parent: null},
{id: 6, parent: 3},
{id: 1, parent: null},
{id: 4, parent: 7},
{id: 2, parent: 1},
{id: 7, parent: 2}
```

I need it to look similar to this:

```
{id: 5, parent: null, children: [
  {id: 3, parent: 5},
  {id: 6, parent: 3}
]},
{id: 1, parent: null, children: [
  {id: 2, parent: 1},
  {id: 7, parent: 2},
  {id: 4, parent: 7},
]}
```

I think the way I did it uses too much loops. Is there a better way?

```js
let items = [
    {id: 3, parent: 5},
    {id: 5, parent: null},
    {id: 6, parent: 3},
    {id: 1, parent: null},
    {id: 4, parent: 7},
    {id: 2, parent: 1},
    {id: 7, parent: 2}
  ];
  let itemsNew = [];

  items = items.map(function(x){
    return {id: x.id, parent: x.parent, children: []};
  });

  // new array with parents only
  for(let i=items.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    if(items[i].parent == null){
      itemsNew.push(items[i]);
      items.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  for(let i=0; i<itemsNew.length; i++){
    let childIndexes = findChildAll(itemsNew[i].id);

    // sort the indexes so splicing the array wont misplace them
    childIndexes.sort(function(a,b){
      return b-a;
    });
    
    for(let j=0; j<childIndexes.length; j++){
      itemsNew[i].children.push(items[childIndexes[j]]);
      items.splice(childIndexes[j], 1);
    }
  }

  // returns an array of indexes of all the element's children and their children
  function findChildAll(parentId){
    for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
      if(items[i].parent == parentId){
        let resultArray = findChildAll(items[i].id);
        // is the result as an array add it to the index
        if(resultArray) return [i].concat(resultArray);
        // otherwise return just this index
        return [i];
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(itemsNew);
```

Comment: thats rather a tree than a 2D array

Comment: Your question might potentially be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - we don't normally deal with already-working code. Here, we deal with bugs primarily.

Comment: @ADyson Today I decided to not take risks and spend a few hours solving it before posing here, since in the past I was told this "Isn't a code writing service"

Comment: well, it's not, that's true. But that's unrelated to whether you're asking for a code review as opposed to a bug fix. Unless your code is actually presenting a _problem_ (e.g. it runs really slowly), then as far as we're concerned it works. If you want to write it more neatly or something, then that's a job for a code review, not a bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it a lot by utilizing `filter`:

```
  for(const item of items) 
    item.children = items.filter(child => child.parent === item.id);

 const parents = items.filter(item => !item.parent);
```

Or if there are lots of nodes, might be benefitial for performance to use a Map:

```
 const itemsByID = new Map(items.map(item => [item.id, item]));

 const parents = [];

 for(const item of items) {
   if(item.parent) {
     const parent = itemsByID[item.parent];
     if(!parent.children) parent.children = [];
     parent.children.push(item);
  } else parents.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finding the children could be slow if the array gets big because the function searches always in the full array

```
const withParent = items.filter((item) => item.parent !== null);
const getDeepIdsWithId = (id) => {
    const result = [];
    while (true) {
        const i = withParent.find((item) => item.parent === id);
        if (!i) {
            break;
        }
        id = i.id;
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
};
const parent = items.filter((item) => item.parent === null).map((item) => ({...item, children: getDeepIdsWithId(item.id)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a recursive approach some like this:

```
const array1 = [{id: 3, parent: 5},
    {id: 5, parent: null},
    {id: 6, parent: 3},
    {id: 1, parent: null},
    {id: 4, parent: 7},
    {id: 2, parent: 1},
    {id: 7, parent: 2}];

const getChild = (origi, fathers) => 
    origi.filter(
        originEle => originEle.parent && fathers.some(f => f.id === originEle.parent)
    )

const getChildren = (originArray, fathers) => {
    let childs = getChild(originArray, fathers);

    let continueFetching = childs && childs.length > 0;

    while (continueFetching) {
        const moreChilds = getChild(originArray, childs)
            .filter(m => !childs.some(c => c.id === m.id))

        if (
            moreChilds && 
            moreChilds.length > 0
        ) {
            childs = childs.concat(moreChilds);
            continueFetching = true;
        } else {
            continueFetching = false;
        }
    }

    return childs;
}

const result = array1
    .filter(
        a1 => !a1.parent
    )
    .map(
        aFather => ({
            id: aFather.id,
            parent: null,
            children: getChildren(array1, [aFather])
        })
    )
```